# Discord.py asyncio.sleep

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10,commands.BucketType.user)
async def barrels(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.message.author

    await asyncio.sleep(2100)
    await ctx.send("The barrel timer has been started.")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} The barrels are almost ready to be picked up!")
```

Hello, I was wondering if there is a way to add a "Check" persay to see if the asyncio.sleep(2100) is already active and if it is then to not allow it. I'm fairly new to using asyncio and could not find anything after looking for a bit.

I tried using an if statement but that obviously did not work. I haven't tried to much. It's mainly just research that I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to simply use `max_concurrency`

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.max_concurrency(1, commands.BucketType.user)
async def barrels(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.message.author

    await ctx.send("The barrel timer has been started.")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} The barrels are almost ready to be picked up!")
    await asyncio.sleep(2100)
```

If the command is active (it hasn't finished execution, 'cause of `asyncio.sleep`) it won't allow the user to run the command again.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t even know this was a thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please do accept the answer if you think it's helpful @ClydeOwens